# Apache htaccess on Win2k is not being processed

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite URLs using mod_rewrite.  It is enabled in httpd.conf and url rewriting works if the lines are in the httpd.conf file.  However, I would like the rules to be in the .htaccess file.
It doesn't appear that .htaccess is being processed at all by Apache on Win2k.

I have ReWriteLogging turned all the way up, but the log file isn't being created.  The last line in httpd.conf is

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

.htaccess contents

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteLog "c:/rewrite.log" 
RewriteLogLevel 15
RewriteRule /alice.html$ /bob.html
```

Thanks

edit : Apache version 2.2 on Windows 2k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that `AllowOverride FileInfo` is enabled in `httpd.conf` for the directories affected; see also http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride. You might also check permissions on the `.htaccess` files themselves, to ensure there's nothing preventing Apache from reading them.